# Malloc in constructors

Tags: c++, class, constructor, malloc, oop

I'm implementing a binary heap class. The heap is implemented as an array that is dynamically allocated. The heap class has members capacity, size and a pointer to an array, as:

```
class Heap
{
    private:
       Heap* H;
       int capacity; //Size of the array.
       int size; //Number of elements currently in the array
       ElementType* Elements; //Pointer to the array of size (capacity+1)

       //I've omitted the rest of the class.
};
```

My construcor looks like this:

```
Heap::Heap (int maxElements)
{
    H = ( Heap* ) malloc ( sizeof ( Heap ) );
    H -> Elements = ( ElementType* ) malloc ( ( maxElements+1 )*sizeof ( ElementType ) );
    H -> Elements[0] = DUMMY_VALUE; //Dummy value
    H -> capacity = maxElements;
    H -> size = 0;  
}
```

Since I'm mallocing twice and dereferencing both pointers in the constructor, I should check whether it succeeds. But what should I do if it fails? The constructor can't itself return anything to indicate that it failed. Is it good programming practice to avoid mallocs in constructors altogether?

Comment: Hello, @Sahil! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Thank you for pasting the code that is relevant to your question, but please format it as code when you ask your next question (indent each line four spaces, or use the button labelled `{}`). Also, I don't think you need your `H` member variable at all. The space for the `Heap` object has already been allocated by the time your constructor is entered. You just need to allocate space for the `Elements` array.

Comment: I don't understand why your Heap object has a pointer to another Heap object inside it, especially when you don't use the members of the object you're constructing. I would lose the first `malloc` and use the members of your object directly.

Comment: Actually it's quite bad practice to have the pointer `H` point to the memory where the constructor didn't run. I can bet that dereferencing `H` invokes undefined behaviour. Why not just store `capacity`, `size` and `Elements` directly in your class?

Comment: It's good programming practice to avoid `malloc` in C++ code, not just constructors.  Search for RAII and `operator new`, and then research smart pointers, for preferred C++ approaches to memory management.

Comment: Use a vector internally.

Comment: I'll make sure I format it correctly the next time I post, @Rob. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First of all, you do **not** need a `Heap*` member variable inside your `Heap` object, and you certainly should not be allocating memory for it in the `Heap` constructor - that's just asking for trouble. Nor should you be accessing your member variables as `H->Elements`, but rather simply as `Elements`.

The only thing you need to allocate is the `Elements` array.

With regards to handling allocation failures, constructors should indicate failures via an exception. There is even a standard exception type, `std::bad_alloc` that is usually used to indicate a failure to allocate memory.

For example:

```
#include <stdexcept>  // for std::bad_alloc
...
Heap::Heap (int maxElements) 
{
    Elements = ( ElementType* ) malloc ( ( maxElements+1 )*sizeof ( ElementType ) );
    if (Elements == NULL)
        throw std::bad_alloc("Failed to allocate memory");
    ...
}
```

Even better, use `new` rather than `malloc` to allocate the memory. `new` will automatically throw an exception of type `std::bad_alloc` if it fails to allocate memory.

Example:

```
Heap::Heap (int maxElements) 
{
    Elements = new ElementType[maxElements + 1];  // throws std::bad_alloc on failure
    ...
}
```

Note: if you use `new` to allocate the object, you must use `delete` to free it rather than `free`. (**Correction**: In the example above, you are using the array form of new, `new[]`, so you should call the array form of delete, `delete[]`).

Finally, you haven't shown how `ElementType` is declared, but if it's a type that has a non-default constructor/destructor (or if it's a template parameter which  means it can potentially be such a type), you **have** to use `new` rather than `malloc` when allocating it because `malloc` will not call the constructor (and `free` will not call the destructor). In general, it's good practice to just always use `new` and `delete` in C++ rather than `malloc` and `free`.

Comment: @Roddy But it isn't `new Heap`, it's `Heap * H = (Heap*)malloc(sizeof(Heap))` - the constructor won't be called ;-)

Comment: If you use `new[]`, don't use `delete` -- use `delete[]`!

Comment: @Khaled: Roddy was commenting on my answer which originally recommended replacing `H = (Heap*)malloc(sizeof(Heap))` with `H = new Heap`. That's before I realized just how wrong that was...

Answer (score 5):

You should learn some basic C++ 'rules of the road', the first of which is:

*Use the Standard Template Library!*

```
class Heap {
  private: 
    std::vector<ElementType> elements;
}
```

And your constructor? You don't need one.

In general, any use of `malloc()` or `free()` in C++ is a 'code smell'. It's a sure-fire way of ending up with incorrectly constructed objects, buffer overflows, and memory leaks. Use `new` and `delete`, preferably with smart pointers.

Or, better yet. just have your objects constructed statically whenever possible.

Answer (score 1):

You're allocating the object in its own constructor? Doesn't make sense:

```
    H = ( Heap* ) malloc ( sizeof ( Heap ) );
```

Constructor is called by the `new` operator, right after the memory allocation. If you're trying to create a singleton - use a static method which will instantiate the object, and call

```
class Heap{
public:
   static Heap* Get();
private:
   Heap();
   static Heap* H;
}

Heap *Heap::H = 0;

Heap * Heap::Get()
{
    if (!H)
       H = new (Heap);
    return H;
}

Heap::Heap()
{ 
    // whatever else
}
```

To your question: `malloc` is a C function. In C++ - use `new`. You don't need to check for return values then, `new` will throw exception on failure.

Comment: Yes, that bit doesn't make sense. But that isn't an answer to his question, merely a useful observation on your part. Maybe this should be a comment instead of answer?